# Unable to return Doubly Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

My code will read data from `.txt` file into a doubly linked list. You guys please take a look and tell me what has been wrong here.

```
TelephoneBookList * commandLoad(char* fileName) {
    TelephoneBookList *(*createList)(TelephoneBookNode*, char[]) = createTelephoneBookList;

    char entry[100];
    TelephoneBookList* aList = NULL;
    TelephoneBookNode* aNode = NULL;
    FILE* telephoneListFile = NULL;

    telephoneListFile = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if (!telephoneListFile)
        return NULL;
    else {
        while (!feof(telephoneListFile)) {
            fgets(entry, 100, telephoneListFile);

            if (strstr(entry, "#")) //skip the first 2 lines in text file
                continue;

            aList = (*createList)(aNode, entry); //call the below function
            countEntry++;
        }

    aList->size = countEntry;
    fclose(telephoneListFile);

    return aList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where dos it crash ? Did you try to use a debugger ?

Comment: You do not read the file correctly, use `while (fgets(..) != NULL) {...}` instead. As you have it now if fgets encounters end of file you still create a node.

Comment: `aList = malloc(sizeof aList);` --> `aList = malloc(sizeof *aList);` and `aList = (*createList)(aNode, entry);` --> `aList = createList()` move to before loop. and `addNodeToList(aList, entry);` instead of.

Comment: Thank you guys so much! It works now

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
while (!feof(telephoneListFile)) {
    fgets(entry, 100, telephoneListFile);
```

To:

```
while (fgets(entry, 100, telephoneListFile)) {
```